# PHP - Denial of Service Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

When my code goes through a [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_Top_10) scan with our internal software, it throws me the below error:

```
if (preg_match("/^attachment; filename=\"".$_GET['get_part']."\"$/",$part['Content-Disposition']))
```

The explanation they gave is:

> There is a vulnerability in implementations of regular expression evaluators and related methods that can cause the thread to hang when evaluating repeating and alternating overlapping of nested and repeated regex groups. This defect can be used to execute a Denial of Service (DoS) attack.

There are no known regular expression implementations which are immune to this vulnerability.

How to get rid of this ?

Comment: `when evaluating repeating and alternating overlapping of nested and repeated regex groups` Yeah, that would be with this part then `$_GET['get_part']` eh ?

Comment: Try constructing the string before sending it to `preg_match()`.

Comment: They probably don't want you to construct _dynamic_ regex.

Comment: Can you please give me an example as i am not getting it how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use user input directly as part of a regular expression. Use `preg_quote()` to escape it so it will match it literally.

```
if (preg_match("/^attachment; filename=\"".preg_quote($_GET['get_part'], '/')."\"$/",$part['Content-Disposition']))
```

Comment: 3 up-votes but nobody noticed there is no `preg_escape` function in PHP.